# Recover stage state after reset

Tags: git, reset, stage

After `git reset --mixed` my previously staged new files became unstaged.
Is it possible to recover stage state that was before `git reset` execution?

Comment: It *is* possible, using `git fsck --lost-found`, which puts unreferenced blobs into a subdirectory where you can inspect them. It's usually *much* harder than just re-creating them though, as there tend to be very many such blobs, and *all* the names are destroyed, and it's too difficult to figure out which files in the lost+found are which.

Comment: @torek i didn't lose my files, they are just got unstaged

Comment: Note that the `--lost-found` option isn't just for *files*, it also finds dangling commits. However, you *did* lose the copy that was in the staging area. But this is why all of this is commentary, rather than an answer—it's all peripheral stuff around the general idea of how the "staging area" really works. Specifically, the stage holds a *copy* of **every** file that goes into the next commit. When you use `git reset --mixed` you are telling Git: *remove the copies that are in there, and put in copies from `HEAD` instead.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, git does not automatically store the staging history, there is no direct way to restore the index to one of its previous state.

---

In the future, here are some actions you can take :

- commit more often
- a variation : commit then rollback :

  ```
  # add stuff :
  git add ... / git add -p ...

  git commit -m "work in progress"
  git reset --soft HEAD^
  ```

  this will add the created commit in the current branch's reflog,
  using `git reset --soft` will preserve the staging area
- use  `git stash && git stash apply`
  `git stash` creates two commits :

  1. one for the content of the staging area,
  2. one for the content of all modified files

Here is the output of the command :

```
$ git stash && git stash apply
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 7475d1d {message}
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
[...]
```

here is what the stash commits look like :

```
    $ git log --oneline --graph stash@{0}
    *   79d9cd7 (refs/stash) WIP on master: 7475d1d {message} # <- full stash
    |\  
    | * 43f3da0 index on master: 7475d1d {message}            # <- staging area's content
    |/  
    *   7475d1d (HEAD -> master, origin/master) {message}     # <- current active commit
    |\
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-add your files:

```
git add path/to/the/file
```

If only part of the file was staged, you can patch add:

```
git add --patch path/to/the/file
```

Comment: This is what I had to do, but this is complicated when you need to selectively add many files from many different directories and keep other files unstaged as before. That is why I wonder if there is a way to recover stage state in some non-manual way.

Comment: @serhii AFAIK staging has no history. Consider committing early and not worrying so much.

Comment: There are ways to recover what has been staged, in case of `git reset --hard` for example, but in your case you haven't lost the content of your files, so it would not help I am afraid `git add` is the only way here.